# Passing array values from a form: Why I get a 1 variable instead of array?

Tags: html, django, forms

I try to pass the next form by clicking the 'submit' button (I checked the all 2 fields):

```
<form id='contact-form' name='contact-form' method='get' action='/3/'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='v[]' value='1'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='v[]' value='2'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

In my view I output all received variables (using Django framework):

```
@template
def view3( request ):
    print "request={0}".format( request.REQUEST )
    ...
```

I got only the last variable in output:

```
request={u'v[]': u'2'}
```

Is it something wrong with the snippet of html?

**Additional Info**. The html containing the form is in a frame on another html page.

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was wrong I deleted it, but I have a suggestion, are you using single quotes in the real html or is just a copy paste error? It should be with double quotes

Comment: @PauloBu We can use any quotes we want - double or single.

Comment: Don't use field names like `v[]`, that's a PHP-ism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's dictionaries only allow one value per key, therefore Django offers a special type for this case, a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict). To obtain a list of values coming from an input array, you need to call [`getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) on it:

```
v = request.GET.getlist('v')
```